# Find triggers of a form in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, forms, triggers

How can I get the body of triggers in Oracle 10g forms?

I used `ALL_TRIGGERS` but it showed me triggers saved in tables, not in forms.

Comment: Oracle Forms code is stored in a file with extension `.fmb` not in the database.

Comment: @Tony Andrews so I can't get the code of       .fmb files?

Comment: As I recall there is a way to convert a `.fmb` (Forms Binary) file to a more readable `.fmt` (Forms Text) file.  From within Forms Builder menu and/or via a command line "fmconvrt" or similar executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find oracle forms in the .fmb files. You can open .fmb files with a text editor. See [How to Open FMB Files](http://dbaforums.org/oracle/index.php?showtopic=15979) for more information.

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful.

Comment: You can also check the "show pl/sql items" in the view menu. It will hide all items that have no triggers. Very handy in large forms.